Deviation from the optimal solution for Solomon instances of CVRPTW
I tried to make a CVRPTW implementation in Gurobi, especially to solve the Solomon instances, and wanted to compare the found optimal solutions with the best known solutions of the Solomon CVRPTW instances. However, for the C101 instance of group 1, according to the website, the optimal solution in terms of Euclidean distance is 191.3, but my optimal solution with my Gurobi implementation is 191.7 and I wonder how that comes about. Perhaps due to a rounding error? I round to the second decimal place when calculating the Euclidean distances. Here is my implementation:
# Model implementation
distances = {(i, j): round(np.hypot(X[i] - X[j], Y[i] - Y[j]), 1) for i in nodes for j in nodes if i != j}
tempo = distances  # Assuming time is proportional to distance
print(distances)


arcs_vars = [(i,j,k) for i in nodes for j in nodes for k in vehicles if i != j]
arcs_tempos = [(i,k) for i in nodes for k in vehicles]

model = gp.Model("CVRPTW")

# Decision variables
x = model.addVars(arcs_vars, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
t = model.addVars(arcs_tempos, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="t")

# Objective function
model.setObjective(gp.quicksum(distances[i, j] * x[i, j, k] for i, j, k in arcs_vars), GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Ensure each vehicle can start its route from the depot to at most one client
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(x[0, j, k] for j in clients) <= 1 for k in vehicles)

# Ensure each vehicle can return to the depot from at most one client
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(x[i, 0, k] for i in clients) <= 1 for k in vehicles)

# Ensure the number of vehicles leaving the depot equals the number of vehicles returning
model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[0, j, k] for j in clients for k in vehicles) == gp.quicksum(
    x[i, 0, k] for i in clients for k in vehicles))

# Ensure each client is visited exactly once
model.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(x[i, j, k] for j in nodes for k in vehicles if i != j) == 1 for i in clients)

# Ensure flow conservation for each node
model.addConstrs(
    gp.quicksum(x[i, j, k] for j in nodes if i != j) - gp.quicksum(x[j, i, k] for j in nodes if i != j) == 0 for i
    in nodes for k in vehicles)

# Ensure vehicle capacity constraints are respected
model.addConstrs(
    gp.quicksum(q[i] * gp.quicksum(x[i, j, k] for j in nodes if i != j) for i in clients) <= Q[k] for k in vehicles)

# Ensure service time and travel time constraints are respected
model.addConstrs(
    (x[i, j, k] == 1) >> (t[i, k] + s[i] + tempo[i, j] <= t[j, k]) for i in clients for j in clients for k in
    vehicles if i != j)

# Ensure time window constraints are respected
model.addConstrs(t[i, k] >= e[i] for i, k in arcs_tempos)
model.addConstrs(t[i, k] <= l[i] for i, k in arcs_tempos)

# Set a time limit for the optimization
model.Params.timeLimit = 500

# Optimize the model
model.optimize() 


just to be sure, Gurobi's log shows optimality?

Yes:
Explored 1 nodes (1108 simplex iterations) in 0.14 seconds (0.33 work units)
Thread count was 12 (of 12 available processors)
Solution count 2: 191.814 1132.2
Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 1.918136197787e+02, best bound 1.918136197787e+02, gap 0.0000%
Objective value: 191.8136197786562

Here is how you should compute the distance d between node i and node j:
xd = x[i] - x[j]
yd = y[i] - y[j]
e = sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);
d = floor(e * 10);

This way, one gets integer values. If you're not afraid of floating point arithmetic issues, you can divide them by $10$. Otherwise, you need to multiply the time-windows and service times by $10$ as well.

Should be floor(e * 10)/10, right?  The scaling doesn't matter for the objective, but it does for the time windows.

@RobPratt I prefer not to divide and keep integer values to avoid floating point arithmetic issues. Indeed, one needs to scale time windows and service time as well

The error was most likely due to the incorrect specification of the values in the benchmarks on the website. For other Solomon instances, the optimal solutions match the benchmarks!
